# Undefined reference error while compiling C code in windows using VS code

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, mingw

I'm trying to compile a C project. in VS code but I'm getting an error while compiling the project.
This happens only when I'm trying to call a function from a different file.

Including the code below.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mbusApi.h"

int main(){
    printf("hello");
    initMBus();
}
```

**mbusApi.h**

```
#ifndef MBUSAPI_H
#define MBUSAPI_H

void initMBus(void);

#endif // MBUSAPI_H
```

**mbusApi.c**

```
#include "mbusApi.h"

void initMBus(){

}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.c",
                "${fileDirname}\\mbusApi.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                ""
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
            },
            
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
        },
    ]
}
```

While compiling this I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoPonFf.o:main.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `initMBus'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: How do you compile it? Maybe for IDEs, you need to include the files in some sort of workspace, so that compiler knows the existence of all the files, and can compile and link them together?

Comment: `printf("hello");` --> `puts("hello");`

Comment: @SouravGhosh args field in the tasks.json file does the same right?

Comment: maybe, I'm not sure (about IDEs and their configs), sorry.

Comment: Can you show the actual command that was started by vscode when compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested exchanging `"${fileDirname}\\mbusApi.c",` and `"${fileDirname}\\main.c",` ? Because main.c needs mbusApi, maybe try to compile mbusApi first.

It should work with:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${fileDirname}\\mbusApi.c",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.c",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/MinGW/bin"
            },
            
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: removed it still having the same issue.

Comment: I thought that order was important for linking part. Nonetheless.

Comment: yeah, normally it's not important. But maybe tasks.json works in a specific ordrer ? I just use it twice, and I never have this kind of problem (only with one file, I admit xD)